# ReactJs Onclick Not Working If Append To Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pushing JsonArray data to datatable in reactjs through array as following.

```
tableTest= () => { //Function Name
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: "/test" //URL

    })
        .then(response => {
            var testArray= [];
            var slNo = 0;
            response.data.map((item, index) => {
                var result = [];
                slNo++;
                var result = [];
                result.push(slNo);
                result.push(item.id);
                result.push(item.name);
                result.push(item.mob);
                result.push("<button onclick={this.accept}>Accept</button>");
                testArray.push(result);
            })
            this.setState({ testTableTable: testArray});
        }).catch(response => {
            console.log("Error", response);
        })
}
```

If I click the button Accept I get "this.accept" is not a function.

Can anyone please tell me how to write onclick function in Javascript.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you try `result.push(<button onclick={this.accept}>Accept</button>);`

Comment: You mean without double qoutes ? Button will not display. It will show like [ Object Object]

Comment: are you using jQuery alongside?

Comment: Nope. I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: Where is `accept` defined?

Comment: After the code whatever I have posted.

accept = () =>{
}

Comment: Could you share more of your code for a better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of onclick function use column onClick function of datatable the source code as shown below:**

```
 tableTest= () => { 
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: "/test" //URL

        })
            .then(response => {
                var testArray= [];
                var slNo = 0;
                response.data.map((item, index) => {
                    var result = [];
                    slNo++;
                    var result = [];
                    result.push(slNo);
                    result.push(item.id);
                    result.push(item.name);
                    result.push(item.mob);
                    result.push("<button class='accept"+index+"'>Accept</button>");//define class here to use reference for column onClick function
                    testArray.push(result);
                })
                this.setState({ testTableTable: testArray});
            }).catch(response => {
                console.log("Error", response);
            })
    }
```

//Change table to Datatable

```
setDataTableData = () => { //set datatable

    this.$el2 = $(this.el2) //el2 is reference of table
    this.$el2.DataTable(
      {
        data: this.state.RowTableData, //RowTableData is array
       "columnDefs": [

          //column click function goes here
          {
            "targets": 4,// 4th column in a table
            "createdCell": (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) => {

              $(td).on('click', '.accept' + row, () => { //Click on <td>
                this.accept(); //call function here
              })

            }
          }
        ],

      }
    )
}
```

//Accept function Here

```
accept =() =>{
//function here
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(response => {
            var testArray= [];
            window.YOUR_CLICK_FN = this.accept.bind(this);
            var slNo = 0;
            response.data.map((item, index) => {
                var result = [];
                slNo++;
                var result = [];
                result.push(slNo);
                result.push(item.id);
                result.push(item.name);
                result.push(item.mob);
                result.push("<button onclick={YOUR_CLICK_FN}>Accept</button>");
                testArray.push(result);
            })
            this.setState({ testTableTable: testArray});
        }).catch(response => {
            console.log("Error", response);
        })
```

Problem is in refreance binding.

Answer (score 0):

React event handlers are named using camelCase. You should be calling `onClick` instead of `onclick`.

See link below:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

CodeSandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3rp301jjym

Comment: i changed it to onClick . Still same problem

Comment: Make a CodeSandbox of your code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableTest= () => { //Function Name
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: "/test" //URL

    })
        .then(response => {
            var testArray= [];
            var slNo = 0;
            response.data.map((item, index) => {
                var result = [];
                slNo++;
                var result = [];
                result.push(slNo);
                result.push(item.id);
                result.push(item.name);
                result.push(item.mob);
                result.push((<button onclick={this.accept}>Accept</button>));
                testArray.push(result);
            })
            this.setState({ testTableTable: testArray});
        }).catch(response => {
            console.log("Error", response);
        })
}
```

Problem is it is stored as string. So you have to push it as a react component to make it work.

And `onclick` doesn't work in react. You have to use `onClick`

Comment: if we don't use  " " it will display as  " [object Object] " instead of button

Comment: Can you use `()`  instead of  `""`. 
To be more precise use,
`(<button onClick={this.accept}>Accept</button>)` instead of 
`"<button onClick={this.accept}>Accept</button>"`

Comment: I tried with this () that time it will show  " [object Object] ". It will not display a button in table

Comment: Can you provide with code snippet in which you're rendering the table?